# Polymer 3.0 Elements using Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, polymer

Can someone please direct me on how to create Polymer 3.0 Elements using kotlin js?

Problem is The Polymer Element in Javascript is

```
class AndyApp extends PolymerElement {
    static get template() {
        return html`
          <style include="shared-styles">
            :host {
              display: block;
              padding: 10px;
              background-color: #0D334988;
            }
          </style>

          <div class="card">
            <div class="circle">1</div>
            <h1>New View</h1>
            <p>New view!</p>
          </div>
    `;
    }
}

customElements.define("andy-app", AndyApp)
```

The kotlin equivalent I tried to write was

```
class AndyApp : PolymerElement {
    companion object {
        fun getTemplate() {
           . . .
        }

        //also tried
        val template
        get() {
           . . .
        }
    }
}
```

somehow, after compilatation, my `fun template()` or `val template` is available in `AndyApp.Companion.template()` or `AndyApp.Companion.template`, how do I make it compiled to `AndyApp.template()` or `AndyApp.template`?

Another Question that goes with it?: what is the equivalent html`` template literal in kotlin js?